# how to add data in a row or kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, kendo-grid

I have a scenario where I want to fill some of the kendo grid columns by program. So I assume that I have to catch the row and fill data in the columns.

I am able to fetch the row ID based on some event(click for example). But I have no Idea how to update the value of a column bases on row id pragmatically.

http://jsfiddle.net/xojke83s/4/

above is the JS fiddle where I am able to get the row ID of a particular row. I want to know the way  fill some data in any of the column by program. In the above example that column should be operationContext.

following is the code for same -

```
<div id="grid"></div>

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    "dataSource": {
                      "schema": {
                        "model": {
                          "id": "id",   
                          "fields": {       
                            "OperationContext": {
                              "type": "string",                              
                              "editable": "false"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }                     
                    },
                    "editable": "popup",
                    "toolbar": [
                      {
                        "name": "create",
                        "text": "Add a New Record"
                      }
                    ],
                    "columns": [
                      {

                        "field": "Name",
                        "title": "Name"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Age",
                        "title": "Age"

                      },
                      {
                        "field": "OperationContext",
                        "title": "Operation Context"
                      },
                      { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
                         ]
                        });

          $(".k-grid-add").on("click", function () {

              var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data([{OperationContext: "IsAdded"}]);

           });

//bind click event to the checkbox
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"); 
grid.bind("edit", grid_edit); 

function grid_edit(e){

    console.log(e.model.uid);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: should this `default` setting nature only apply to newly created items or should it also override existing items?

Comment: it is for newly added or edited or deleted rows

Comment: i have updated your fiddle with this: http://jsfiddle.net/xojke83s/6/ is this the sort of thing you are looking for? It will only add the text in for new items and where an id is greater than 0. I can see the logic for newly created items and maybe for edited items if the value is blank or if it is being used as a `status` tracker . But if you delete an item then surely that is deleted from your datasource and you will no longer have access to that item so why store an update/indicate an update to a value when it is to be deleted.

Comment: yeah its kind of same thing.. please make it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer made from comment as requested**

I have updated your fiddle with this: [updated js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xojke83s/6)

I have modified the edit code to do this:

```
function grid_edit(e){

    console.log(e.model);

    if(!e.model.isNew() || e.model.id === 0){
        e.model.set("OperationContext","I am being updated");
    }

}
```

It will only add the inserting (`defaultValue`) and updating text in for new items or where an id is greater than 0.

I can see the logic for newly created items and maybe for edited items if the value is blank or if it is being used as a status tracker.

But if you delete an item then surely that is deleted from your `datasource` and you will no longer have access to that item so why store an update/indicate an update to a value when it is to be deleted.

Comment: The only thing which differs I need to fire a different event on edit button and delete button, if you can suggest those events that would be great help.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted.